# How to reference the special SQL Server trigger table called: "updated" on error: Invalid object name 'updated'.?

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

When I select from the "updated" table in a trigger, I get the error message:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure foobar, Line 81
Invalid object name 'updated'.
```

I'm setting up a trigger to update children to be the same value as their parent when the parent gets updated. I try to refer to the "updated" table as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017).

I've checked that the database is right with a USE database statement up top.

```sql
    CREATE TABLE foo ( bar int )
    GO

    CREATE TRIGGER foobar ON foo
        AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    SELECT bar FROM inserted ;
    SELECT bar FROM updated  ; --> problem!
    SELECT bar FROM deleted  ;
    GO

    INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3) ;
    UPDATE foo SET bar = 2 WHERE bar = 3;
```

I expect to see a 2 or a three (ie. the before image or after image) from the selects, but the `select * from updated` produces the error: `Invalid object name 'updated'.`

Comment: Because "updated" doesn't exist. There is only inserted and deleted. Inserted has the new values and deleted has the old values.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks Sean

Comment: Microsoft if you're listening, this was confusing because the words `inserted` and `deleted` are so close to the past participle of the `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` reserved words. it would be great if these tables had synonyms that correspond linguistically with `old-values` / `new-values` or `image-before` / `image-after` syntax, even if the semantics are the same.

Comment: LOL there is no chance MS is going to change the names of these tables. They have been that way for decades now. And honestly the past participle seems to be exactly what would make sense here. The inserted table contains the values as a result of an insert statement. Keeping the names close the statement that generates the values makes tons of sense. Definitely NOT image in the name as that indicates a datatype (now deprecated).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server uses two types of bridge tables (inserted and deleted) for helping the trigger to achieve 'insert', 'update', 'delete'.

Here is the reference from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017